# HTTPS & WSS Setup for Deepstream?

Tags: ssl, express, deepstream.io

Could you point me to a setup for Deepstream with SSL configured for Express and Deepstream?

I'm primarily seeing the following error after attempting to configure for https and wss. Also, I am using a self-signed certificate.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://127.0.0.1:8082/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://127.0.0.1:6020/engine.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
initializeKeys : function() {
    this.ssl = {};
    this.ssl.cert = fs.readFileSync('./keys/cert.pem', 'utf8');
    this.ssl.key = fs.readFileSync('./keys/key.pem', 'utf8');
},

initializeSecureWebServer: function() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var https = require('https');
    var credentials = {key: this.ssl.key, cert: this.ssl.cert};
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../client'));
    app.use('/shell', express.static(__dirname + '/../shell'));
    var server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
    server.listen(8082);
},

initializeDeepstreamServer: function() {
    this.server = new DeepstreamServer();
    this.server.set('host', '127.0.0.1');
    this.server.set('port', 6020);
    this.server.set('sslCert', this.ssl.cert);
    this.server.set('sslKey', this.ssl.key);
},
```

Answer (score 9):

The solution was that for the client in the browser I forgot to change:

```
var client = deepstream('127.0.0.1:6020');
```

to:

```
var client = deepstream('wss://127.0.0.1:6020');
```

There's the simple obvious answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Adding a simple code to demonstrate this.

```
const ds = require('deepstream.io-client-js');

const client = ds('wss://127.0.0.1:6020', {
  subscriptionTimeout: 500000,
}).login();

client.on('error', (msg, event, topic) => {
  console.error(`[${event}][${topic}]  Deepstream Error: ${msg}`);
});

// Client A
client.event.subscribe('dp/channel', data => {
  // handle published data
console.log(data);
})

// Client B
client.event.emit('dp/channel', { some: 'data1' });
module.exports = client;
```